# Migrating Web service to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-migrate

I think, previously cloud services (classic) used for any web service deployment.

What Azure service to choose for migrating Web service or Web API or WCF service ? What needs to be considered before and after migration. Is there any guide available?

Thanks.

Comment: Cloud Services were used more for back end and web deployments. For web service deployments, Azure offers App Services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview

Comment: give this one a try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-app-service-migration-assistant-for-asp-net-applications/